# What exactly are Norways problems with the NH-90?

Tags: aircraft-design, military, helicopter

Several news sources ([here](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/norway-scraps-helicopter-contract-with-france-s-nhindustries-271654843775?mod=investing), or [here](https://www.navalnews.com/naval-news/2022/06/norway-terminates-its-contract-for-the-nh90/)) report that Norway wants to terminate its contract with NH Industries and they want to *return* their delivered NH-90 helicopters. The citation goes as follows:

*"“Regrettably we have reached the conclusion that no matter how many hours our technicians work, and how many parts we order, it will never make the NH90 capable of to meeting the requirements of the Norwegian Armed Forces."*

What exactly are the requirements that the NH-90 is unable to reach? To clarify, I am interested in which exact technical details/requirements are violated that leads norway to conclude that "it will never make the NH90 capable of meeting the requirements"

Comment: Is this really on topic here?

Comment: The help center states: "Aviation Stack Exchange is a site for pilots, engineers, controllers, mechanics, and aviation enthusiasts. If you have a question about [...] Aircraft Design and Manufacture." I would argue that this is a question about the design (because of the requirements). Dont you agree?

Comment: No, I do not agree that this is a question about aircraft design, I really struggle to see how it can be seen in that perspective

Comment: Well I do ask about the exact set of requirements. I assumed that there are a quantifiable number of requirements which cannot be reached (e.g. Door too small, or landing gear fails). Perhaps you think that this question goes too much into politics? If so I would respond that obviously a certain political aspect is involved in the discussion, but I am interested in the exact *technical* reasons for rejecting the NH-90. Therefore to the best of my knowledge the question is not oppinion based and thus on topic. If I am mistaken, please indicate what the exact problem is.

Comment: if you really are interested only in the technical side of things, please specify as much in the question. also, specify the side of "technical". the answer that you got so far is technical, but as WPNSGuy says, it is nowhere close to be a "design" thing.

Comment: I tried to sharpen the question towards the exact technical details, but given that the questions jumps back and forth between 0, 1 and 2 upvotes, I think you might not be the only one who doubts the correctness of the question :D.

Comment: @U_flow - It appears to be a lack of flyable aircraft. The contract was for 14 airframes, capable of sustaining 3,900 flying hours annually. For whatever reason, it does not appear it can do that. Either too few airframes, or the ones they have are too maintenance intensive. "We've been screwing with these things for 20 years, and can't keep them in the air long enough. Cancel the contract, see ya goodbye."

Comment: @WPNSGuy Yes, but I wonder if there are similar capability deficiencies as australia identified for the Eurocopter Tiger: https://www.flightglobal.com/australian-government-auditor-slams-tiger-attack-helicopter/121607.article. I guess that my question entails if the low availability of the NH90 is the only deficiency identified or if there are also other reasons...

Comment: @U_flow - Why should there be similarities? Different manufacturers, different missions, different capabilities, different aircraft...completely different problems.

Comment: @WPNSGuy Well both are *european* helicopters, one manufactured by AHD and the other one partially manufactured by AHD. But I get your point. This must not necessarily mean that the same problem exists on the two helicopters, but I wanted to see if anyone had any further insights on this topic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What exactly are the requirements that the NH-90 is unable to reach?

It appears delivery and availability. Not everything is a "design" issue.

It says right in your second link:

> Norway’s acquisition of the NH90 began in 2001, with 14 helicopters for Coast Guard and Anti-Submarine Warfare duties originally slated for delivery by the end of 2008. As of today, only eight have been delivered in a fully operational configuration. The fleet is currently required to provide 3.900 flight hours annually but in recent years it has averaged only about 700 hours.

Over a decade late, only 8 of 14 aircraft contracted for, and only 700 of the required 3,900 annual flight hours.

Comment: In December 2021 Australia announced early retirement for its 47 NH90s, which entered service in 2014, blaming "unreliability” and cost.

Comment: If they have the same problems as the Dutch Navy, the helicopters are extremely unreliable and need far more than the originally estimated maintenance hours and waiting for spare parts.